# Format a number to NOT have commas (1,000,000 -> 1000000) in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery: How do we format a number that will be part of the result set that should be not having commas: like 1,000,000 to 1000000 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your data type is string here.

You can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to remove certain symbols from strings.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("1,000,000", r',', '') AS Output
```

Returns:

```
+-----+---------+
| Row | Output  |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | 1000000 |
+-----+---------+
```

If your data contains strings with and without commas, this function will return the ones without as they are so you don't need to worry about filtering the input.

Documentation for this function can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace).

Comment: Thanks Eric. It helped!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If performance is your concern, you can use just `REPLACE` function for such simple cases to avoid regular expressions, which are generally slower (see for example [this benchmark](https://fluca1978.github.io/2020/07/09/ReplaceVSRegexpReplace.html)). Then the query would look like this:

`SELECT REPLACE("1,000,000", ',', '' AS Output`